# Using OkHttp 3.9.0 with Dagger 2.11 - Why must I include dagger-android2.x dependency?

Tags: android, dagger-2, okhttp

I was using okhttp 3.8 with dagger 2.11, it works great. When I changed to okhttp 3.9 I was getting  ERROR javax.annotation.Nullable not found.

So by some luck I tried including the dagger-android2.x dependency and that fixed the error.

I understood that If you want to use classes like DaggerActivity or if you want to inject activities or fragments you must include the dagger.android package, but why do I need to include it for OkHttp to be used with Dagger?

Edit: I did some more investigating. 
This change in the https://github.com/square/okhttp/commit/d4a9cf4772ae9d8991e58d934dea433798c9b8eb#diff-e88e53bd5c3b6fb1ba650f55b1261052R21

+import javax.annotation.Nullable;

is the problem.I had to include:

implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2' to fix the error

Update 2:

I was injecting into my websocket listener, which I really didn't need to do. This caused the ERROR javax.annotation.Nullable not found. I changed my code to not inject into the websocketlistener and the error is gone and no need for additional dependencies, the error was entirely my fault.

Comment: You really don't have to include the Dagger Android package, this seems to be some unrelated issue

Comment: Its definitely related. I invalidated the cache, deleted .gradle folder and deleted all generated code. I removed all references to okhttp and confirmed that the code compiles without okhttp included. I then did the same but included okhttp3.8 still compiled fine. I did the same again but this time included okhttp 3.9 and the error appears and the project fails to compile.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually have to include the `dagger-android2.x` dependency. What happens is that OkHttp 3.9 now uses the `javax.annotation.Nullable`, which the `dagger-android2.x` dependency uses internally and is, therefore, also available for OkHttp through gradle merge.

Adding `compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'` to your project should be enough, as you pointed out.